# Trying to send a message to multiple discord servers

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Heres my code. I'm trying to send a message to multiple servers when a user types a command !sendall. For example, when the user types !sendall Hello, it will send "Hello" to multiple discord servers. Thanks for the help!

When doing this, I get this error

```
(node:14424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: guild is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\16034\Desktop\Bot Monitors\bot.js:52:56)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\16034\Desktop\Bot Monitors\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageC
```

```js
// Main
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

var guildList = ["707366229446492208", "704552256007307364"];

// Bootup
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels of ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`); 
  client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`);
});

// Guild Logs
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
  console.log(`New guild joined: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id}). This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`);
});
client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
  console.log(`I have been removed from: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id})`);
  client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`);
});

// Required
client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // Sendall
  if(command === "sendall") 
        try {
            guildList.forEach(guild => guild.defaultChannel.send("messageToSend"));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Could not send message to " + guild.name);
        }
});
client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use an ID to send a message to a Guild. you need to first use that ID to find the guild.

```js
guildList.forEach(guildID => client.guilds.get(guildID).defaultChannel.send('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`guildList` is an array of strings (the IDs), not the guilds itself. You need to get the guild object first.

Also, you can't use `try` and `catch` like that because the thing that may throw (`guild.defaultChannel.send("messageToSend")`) is in the `forEach` function, so the error won't be caught. The error you received was because you attempted to refer to `guild` in your `catch` block. `guild` only exists in the `forEach` function.

Try this:

```js
if(command === "sendall") 
  guildList
    .map(id => client.guilds.cache.get(id))
    .forEach(guild => guild.defaultChannel
      .send("messageToSend")
      .catch(err => console.log("Could not send message to " + guild.name))
    );
}
```

Comment: Its giving me this error, (node:36688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `defaultChannel` was deprecated in v11 and [removed in v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#guild-defaultchannel). That's probably why `defaultChannel` is `undefined`.